# ActionCable: close the connection manually from front-end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I can not close my socket manually.
It quits only when I close a tab in the browser.

```
Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-29 16:55:49 +0200
```

But when I call either

```
App.cable.subscriptions.remove(App.subscription)
```

or

```
App.subscription.unsubscribe()
```

the method "unsubscribed" in `CommunityChannel` is being called, but the cable is still present and I can still print it in my function "print_socket"

How to manually close the connection?

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base

    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
      if current_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_id])
        current_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: TMI in the question. I believe you can make it shorter.

Comment: thanks, and sorry for the long post, i was stuck on it all the day:)

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495351/how-to-close-connection-in-action-cable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`App.cable.subscriptions.remove(App.subscription)` will unsubscribe you from "CommunityChannel", but won't close your connection,

If you want to disconnect, then just do:

`App.cable.disconnect()`