# How to close connection in Action cable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

How to disconnect a client in Action cable (rails 5)?
I would like the user to be completely disconnected (similar to when he closes the tab).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Disconnecting a client from your rails application

If you want to disconnect a client from the rails application, use the `disconnect` method as described in the documentation:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/RemoteConnections.html

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user
    ....
  end
end

ActionCable.server.remote_connections.where(current_user: User.find(1)).disconnect
```

### Disconnecting from the client side

If you want to disconnect the user from the client side you can use the `disconnect` and `unsubscribe` functions in your javascript:

```
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(...)

// Closes the websocket connection.
App.cable.disconnect();

// Unsubscribe from a actioncable subscription (without disconnecting the websocket connection)
App.example = App.cable.subscriptions.create(..);
App.example.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: this drops the subscription or subscriptions - but it doesn't close the websocket.

Comment: @ConfusedVorlon yes, this answer doesn't appear correct.

Comment: I updated the answer to have the client close the connection entirely. @TomRossi

Answer (score 12):

I found this inside **/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actioncable-5.0.1/lib/action_cable/remote_connections.rb**

> If you need to disconnect a given connection, you can go through the
>   RemoteConnections. You can find the connections you're looking for by 
>   searching for the identifier declared on the connection. For example:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user
    ....
  end
end

ActionCable.server.remote_connections.where(current_user: User.find(1)).disconnect
```

> This will disconnect all the connections established for
>   User.find(1), across all servers running on all machines,
>   because   it uses the internal channel that all of these servers are
>   subscribed to.

Hope this will be useful. Looks like it works even in Rails console.

Answer (score 4):

## Disconnecting from the client

I stumbled across this issue too. But I could not believe that there is no simple way to disconnect the websocket connection from the client (without doing an API call). Luckily this works for me:

```
// Create consumer
window.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(...)

// Subscribe to channels
window.cable.subscriptions.create('SomeChannel', ...);

// At some point we want to disconnect (e.g. when user logs out)
window.cable.subscriptions.consumer.disconnect();
```

Comment: when I do this, should I see the websocket under the Network > WS go away? I see in console the connection has ended but I still see the WS in console lingering.

Comment: @NickRes I'm seeing the same thing (four years later). But if I tap on the connection under the WS tab, and then tap on the 'Response' subtab, I see 'Connection Closed'

Answer (score 2):

to disconnect from the client side (in js), call

```
App.cable.disconnect();
```

to disconnect from the server side - see the answer from @prograils

Answer (score 1):

My work around was to create a new route just for disconnect.

```
def disconnection
    ActionCable.server.remote_connections.where(connected_user: user_params['email']).disconnect

   render json: {}, status: 200 
end
```

The client side would have to call the endpoint... something like

```
PUT  /api/cable/disconnection
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing all websocket connections from a `channel`,

```rb
connection.close
```

Unsubscribing from client side

```js
App.cable.disconnect();
```

Disconnecting from outside connection/channel

```rb
ActionCable.server.remote_connections.where(current_user: User.find(params[:id])).disconnect
```